# What is good coding idiom to decompose a complicated expression?

Tags: c++, idioms

My question regards coding style and the decomposition of complicated expressions in C++.

My program has a complicated hierarchy of classes composed of classes composed of classes, etc.  Many of the program's objects hold pointers to, or indices into, other objects.  There are a few namespaces.  As I said, it's complicated—by which I mean that it is a pretty typical 10,000-line C++ program.

A problem of scale emerges.  My code is starting to have lots of unreadable expressions like `p->a(b.c(r).d()).q(s)->f(g(h.i()))`.  (As I said, it's unreadable.  I have trouble reading it, and I was the one who wrote it!  You can just look at it to catch the mood.)  I have tried rewriting such expressions as

```
{
    const I  ii = h.i();
    const G &gg = g(ii);
    const C &cc = b.c(r);
    // ..
    T *const qq = aa.q(s);
    qq->f(gg);
}
```

All those locally scoped symbols arguably make the code more readable, but I admit that I do not care for the overall style.  After all, some of the local symbols are `const &` references, while others represent copies of data.  What if I accidentally omitted one of the `&`, thereby invoking an unnecessary copy of some large object?  My compiler would hardly warn me.

Besides, the version with the local symbols is verbose.

Neither solution suits.  Does there not exist a more idiomatic, less bug-prone way to decompose unreadable expressions in C++?

**ILLUSTRATION**

If a minimal, compilable illustration of the problem helps, then here is one.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
  private:
    int m1;
    int n1;
  public:
    int m() const { return m1; }
    int n() const { return n1; }
    A(const int m0, const int n0) : m1(m0), n1(n0) {}
};

class B {
  private:
    A a1;
  public:
    const A &a() const { return a1; }
    B(const A &a0) : a1(a0) {}
};

B f(int k) {
    return B(A(k, -k));
}

int main() {

    const B  &my_b = f(15);

    {
        // Here is a local scope in which to decompose an expression
        // like my_b.a().m() via intermediate symbols.
        const A  &aa = my_b.a();
        const int mm = aa.m();
        const int nn = aa.n();
        std::cout << "m == " << mm << ", n == " << nn << "\n";
    }

    return 0;

}
```

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

I doubt that it is relevant to the question, but in case it is:  My program defines several templates, but does not presently use any run-time polymorphism.

**AN ACTUAL EXAMPLE**

One of the commenters has kindly requested an actual example out of my code.  Here it is:

```
bool Lgl::is_order_legal_for_movement(
    const Mb::Mapboard &mb, const size_t ix, Chains *const p_chns1
) {

    if (!mb.accepts_orders()) return false;
    const Basic_mapboard &bmb = mb.basic();
    if (!is_location_valid(bmb, ix, false)) return false;
    const Space            &x = mb.spc(ix);
    if (!x.p_unit()) return true;
    const size_t           cx = x.i_cst_occu();
    const Basic_space     &bx = x.basic();
    const Unit             &u = x.unit();
    const bool           army = u.is_army();
    const bool          fleet = u.is_fleet();
    const Order         order = u.order();
    const size_t           is = u.source();
    const Location         lt = u.target_loc();
    const size_t           it = lt.i_spc;
    const size_t           ct = lt.i_cst;
    // ...

    {   
        const Space        &s = mb.spc(is);
        const Basic_space &bs = s.basic();
        result = ( 
            (army_s && (
                bs.nbor_land(it) || count_chains_if(
                    Does_chain_include(ix), chns_s, false
                )   
            )) || (fleet_s && (
                // By rule, support for a fleet can name a coast,
                // but need not.
                ct == NO_CST
                ? is_nbor_sea_no_cst(bs, cs, it) 
                : is_nbor_sea       (bs, cs, lt) 
            ))  
        ) && is_nbor_no_cst(army, fleet, bx, cx, it);
    }   

    // ...

}
```

Comment: Your sample code symbol names don't do much to help the readability of your question. And use functions instead of chains of expressions.

Comment: Your example classes can be cleaned up easily: Just use `const` and remove the accessors. Suddenly everything is less cluttered. Aside from that, concise and meaningful names always help.

Comment: I really hope you are not using one letter variable names in your actual code, because that's the first reason that example line is hard to read. Anyway, I know that it's not an answer, but that kind of expressions maybe are due to not respecting the [Law of Demeter](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) - which is highly unadvisable.

Comment: It seems that you may be chaining deep sequences of getters and setters. Maybe you're abusing classes as simple "groups of data"?

Comment: @Ke Or maybe think "using OOP" means all members must be hidden.

Comment: @KerrekSB:  I did not know that using classes as groups of data was abuse.  Is it?  My classes all have associated member functions other than just getters, if that is what you mean.  I don't have many setters, but mostly prefer to use constructors for that.

Comment: Does `Lgl` have any data / Is that a static function?

Comment: @Deduplicator:  Right.  Not a fanatic, but I do hide *most* members.  I suppose that my coding style is not actually OOP, since it lacks run-time polymorphism.  Anyway, would you advise me not to hide members?

Comment: @Deduplicator:  `Lgl::` is a namespace.  (By the way, thank you for reading my actual code.  I am flattered.  I never expected anyone here to do that.)

Comment: Well, a class should serve some function other than just passing through some member. With the right level of responsibility, hopefully you'll have shorter call chains. It's just a guideline of course.

Comment: I find your code hard to read, not because it is complicated, but because the style of formatting and complete lack of whitespace.

Comment: I like your code the way it is. Adding temporary variables only makes it worse.

Comment: @javidcf:  I have tried to follow the Law of Demeter, though I had not known it by that name.  It is still possible that I have not adequately followed it, though.

Comment: @EJP:  *Adding temporary variables only makes it worse,* you say.  I may be starting to realize that you are right.

Comment: You would actually get much more and probably better advice on CodeReview SE. Just be prepared. They sometimes like to mincemeat code and author to make it good and nice =). For starters I would store partial results of complicated expressions, and giving them a meaningful name. I mean, this `army_s && (bs.nbor_land(it) || count_chains_if( Does_chain_include(ix), chns_s, false ) )` must mean something... and maybe not to obfuscate variable names by assigning them to some one/two letter names. I'd say you put your temporary variables in wrong places. But I am not good at this.

Comment: @thb Didn't mean to sound preachy, good OOP design is easier said than done (if possible at all).

Comment: @luk32:  You are right about the variable names.  As it happens, in this particular program, the two-letter variables are named according to a system that is more or less consistent across all source files -- so you would not find these particular two-letter names unreadable if you (for some reason) were reviewing my entire program.  I should look into CodeReview SE.  Thanks.

Comment: @Deduplicator:  Something you wrote has just penetrated:  *Just use const and remove the accessors.*  It has been years since I have considered this point.  You may be right.  I have used accessors because, theoretically, accessors leave one free to alter the internal representation of a class without changing its interface.  But, now that you mention that, I seldom alter an internal representation without changing the interface; so what good is my approach, really?  You make an interesting point.  I shall have to ponder it.

Comment: @thb: THat's known as YAGNI: You ain't gonna need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your actual code example, I can see why you'd like to make it more readable. I'd probably recode it something like this:

```
if (army_s) {
    result = bs.nbor_land(it) || 
            count_chains_if(Does_chain_include(ix), chns_s, false);
} else if (fleet_s) {
    // By rule, support for a fleet can name a coast,
    // but need not.
    if (ct == NO_CST)
        result = is_nbor_sea_no_cst(bs, cs, it);
    else 
        result = is_nbor_sea(bs, cs, lt);
}
result &= is_nbor_no_cst(army, fleet, bx, cx, it);
```

It executes the same logic, including short-circuit evaluations, but is a little better for human interpretation, I think.  I have also encountered compilers that also generate better code with this style versus the very complex compound line the original code contained.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Your use of the bitwise operator `&=` is interesting.  I have sometimes wished that `&&=` existed.  Is the use of `&=` standard style?  (Twelve or fifteen years ago, I seem to remember a version of GCC that stored bools as ints, and did not guarantee that `true` would always be `1`; so I have been loth to use the bitwise operators for boolean logic.  Maybe my concern is outdated?)

Comment: @thb: If the compiler didn't guarantee true as 1 does it matter? 8|1 is still true. So is 8|4|16|1. Etc.